# SQL Server 2008 : What is the best way for inserting big chunk of data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

We need to extract 54M rows from one database to another. Columns of two tables are similar but not exactly same so there is some conversion work to do. I've started a cursor, but is there any better and also performance friendly way for inserting big chunk of data?

Comment: Is that a recurring task or only done once?

Comment: Read [The Data Loading Performance Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd425070(v=sql.100).aspx)

Comment: this process is going to do only one time.

Comment: I've done it by writing a cursor, thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 1):

Performance and logging-wise, the best options to move large amounts of data are with [SSIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) or other bulk operations such as [BCP export/import](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337544.aspx).

Comment: Columns of the tables and meaning of datas are different in both databases, so bcp is not an option in our case.

Comment: In both cases, SSIS or BCP, you can define the query to export or import the data by hand. Obviously we don't know the complexity of how you need to handle the data, but it should all be doable. You can put your normal TSQL with whatever sub queries, CASE expressions etc to either when you export or when you import the data, forming the end result that's required here.

Answer (score 1):

As far as performance I would suggest you could do the following
1) Creating a Stored proc to do the task - you can call stored proc using ssis 
2) Add SQL Agent job if necessary.